# is it possible to use serialport class in c?

Tags: c, windows

im trying to read newline terminated strings using windows api and saw that the serialport class has a serialport.newline member. i want to know if it is possible to use the serialport class in c and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (Microsoft) C, you'd need to call `CreateFile` to get a handle to the serial port, and `_open_osfhandle(handle, _O_TEXT)` to convert it to a file descriptor. You can get a `FILE*` from that file descriptor with `_fdopen`. After that, `fscanf` will read lines.

Answer (score 0):

Serialport is a [.Net class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30swa673%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You cannot use it in C. You will need to create a VC++.Net project(also refered to as C++/CLI) project.